# Django circular import and model issue

Tags: python, django, import, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have two Django `models.py` in two different apps.

`processor app models.py`

```
from address.models import Address
...defining clasess
class Displayble(models.Model):
 # It has no DB fields
```

`address app models.py`

```
from processor.models import Displayable
class Address(models.Model, Displayble):
...some fields, stored in DB
```

Is moving `Dispalyble` class to another file is the only option to resolve this dependency?

Comment: You haven't shown enough information to tell, because we don't know how you use `Address` or `Displayble` in your `processor/models.py`.

Comment: I agree with Alasdair. You could be importing the models to extend a class or you might me using the class inside a method or function. Provide us with a more detailed code and we will probably be able to help you.

Answer (score 9):

Import the `Address` model with django's `apps.get_model`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model.

In your `processor app models.py` replace

```
from address.models import Address
...defining clasess
class Displayble(models.Model):
# It has no DB fields
```

With

```
from django.apps import apps
Address = apps.get_model(app_label='address', model_name='Address')
....go ahead and use Address as though imported
class Displayable(models.Model):
...
```

Comment: Wow, awesome trick. Was goona move all my modles into a dummy app before I found this answer.

Comment: When I try to do this I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

Every answer I see on the internet says I should fix that issue by just using the path to the model as a string in the foreign key relationship, but I'm not trying to use a foreign key relationship here...